# AJAX Password Change

Tags: php, jquery, html, sql, pdo

So i am trying to implement a password change functionality to my site and I want to submit the password form **without** refreshing the page. So I'm trying to use ajax. Here's my html:

```
<form id="change_Pass" action="" method="post">
    Current Password<input type="password" id="change_password" name="change_password"><br>
    New Password<input type="password" id="new_password" name="new_password"><br>
    Verify Password<input type="password" id="verify_password" name="verify_password"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

And then the jquery:

```
$('#change_Pass').submit(function(e){
    $.ajax({
        data: $(this).serialize(), // get the form data
        type: $(this).attr('POST'), // GET or POST
        url: $(this).attr('Private/change_password.php'), // the file to call
        success: function(response) { // on success..
            $('#success_div).html(response); // update the DIV
        },
        error: function(e, x, r) { // on error..
            $('#error_div).html(e); // update the DIV
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

And then the php:

```
<?php
$usr = $_SESSION["username"];
$old_pwd = $_POST["change_password"];
$new_pwd = $_POST["new_password"];

$link = new PDO('mysql:host=*;dbname=*;charset=UTF-8','*','*');
$query = "SELECT *
        FROM Conference
        WHERE Username = :un";

$stmt = $link->prepare($query);

$stmt->bindParam(':un', $usr);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetchAll();

$hash = $row[0]["Password"];
$is_correct = Bcrypt::check($old_pwd, $hash);
if($is_correct) {
    $query = "UPDATE Conference
            SET `Password`=:new_pwd 
            WHERE Username = :usr";

    $stmt = $link->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindParam(':new_pwd', $new_pwd);
    $stmt->bindParam(':usr', $usr);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

But I'm stuck on a few things.
1) How do I post the data to change_password.php rather than serialize it so that I can use `$_POST`?
2) Does the change_password look correct? It's basically checking what the person entered in for `current password` with the existing password in the database. And if they match then it changes the password.

Comment: also make $('#success_div').html(response); // update the DIV correct

Answer (score 1):

Your JS was a bit off. See my comments:

```
$('#change_Pass').submit(function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);                    // It's a good to cache stuff

    $.ajax({
        data: $this.serialize(),
        type: $this.attr('method'),         // You want `method` here
        url: 'Private/change_password.php', // Dunno why you used `attr`
        success: function(response) {
            $('#success_div').html(response);
        },
        error: function(e, x, r) {
            $('#error_div').html(e);
        }
    });

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Also, your password changing logic doesn't look right to me. You're using Bcrypt, so there is no need (and there *never* should be a need) to store your users' passwords in plaintext.

Store the Bcrypt hash of the password instead of the password. That's really the whole point of password hashing.

Comment: this is the correct answer.and you can add the current password checking to change the password for more security issues